Stargazer implementation problems
I have a regression model that is run with Xb and Yb. Xb and Yb are arrays of float with (1000,).
The regression is stored as a regression.linear_model.RegressionResultsWrapper. Now I try to visualize the result using Stargazer to display the results in my paper. However, with my code I get an error:

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

Code:
resultsb = sm.OLS(Yb, sm.add_constant(Xb), missing="drop").fit()
stargazer = Stargazer([resultsb])

I had tried to enter Xb and Yb as dataframe in the regression, which resulted in

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'


can you provide a reproducible example?
